# Struct node deallocation

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I am trying to remove a struct node from a list, but I keep facing the same issue.

```
typedef struct task{ 
  char* id;
  struct task *next;
} task_t;

task_t** init(){    
  task_t **taskArray = malloc(6 * sizeof(task_t *));
  return taskArray;
}

void task_insert(task_t ** arrayTask, char* id, int prio){
  task_t *newTask = (task_t *) malloc (sizeof(task_t));
  newTask->id = id;
  if(*(arrayTask + prio) !=NULL){
    newTask->next = *(arrayTask + prio);
    *(arrayTask + prio) = newTask;
    }
  *(arrayTask + prio) = newTask;
```

}

```
void task_remove(task_t** arrayTask, char* id){
  task_t* auxtask, * auxtask1;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i<arraySize; i++){
    auxtask1 = auxtask = arrayTask[i];
    while(auxtask != NULL){
        if(!strcmp(auxtask->id, id)){
            auxtask1 = auxtask->next;
            free(auxtask);
            printf("Task %s removed with success\n", id);
            return;         
            }
        else {
            auxtask1 = auxtask;
            auxtask = auxtask->next;
             }

     }
   }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to free auxtask. What happens is that somehow the ID field is freed, but not the struct node itself.

Does someone have any clue to what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a line:

```
auxtask1 = auxtask->next;
free(auxtask);
auxtask = auxtask1;        // <-- here
```

Without that, you were freeing `auxtask` and then 'forgetting' its next pointer.  Next time around the loop, you used `auxtask` which pointed to memory that had been freed.

Just a minor point...  It's more normal to use temporaries the other way around.

```
to_delete = auxtask;
auxtask = auxtask->next;
free(to_delete);
```

Comment: But we don't need  its next pointer, has we return from the function right after the printf. We only need to free that particular node of the list, and what's strange is that we only free the id field (of the struct) instead of the struct node itself.

Comment: My mistake, silly me.  Have you sorted it out yet?  You do have an uninitialised `next` pointer when you `insert` the first item in a list.  `malloc` does *not* clear the memory for you.   Either assign `NULL` or use `calloc`.  Same goes when you allocate the task array.  You *must* clear that memory, because you're relying on the empty array containing `NULL` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that because your task array is only allocating space for pointers to task_t, that you have another allocation step somewhere else when you populate the array?

Also, why do you have a list that you're accessing as an array? Why even make it a list?

Comment: Yes, we have an insert function responsible for populating the array as the user inserts new tasks. I'll edit the question with the code.

Comment: Ok, so why does newTask->next point to newTask? The lines:
newTask->next = *(arrayTask + prio);   
*(arrayTask + prio) = newTask;   

looks like circular assignment to me?   

I have to assume that prio is the index of the prior element in the list, and your next points "backwards" for want of a better description. So shouldn't the assignment be:   
newTask->next = *(arrayTask + prio);   
*(arrayTask + prio + 1) = newTask;

Comment: Once again though, I have to ask why you're mixing list and array type accesses? Why don't you just remove the struct task *next field and work with the struct purely as an array?

Comment: No you're seeing it wrong I think, I had to make the scheme to be sure but basically what we have is an 6 position array with pointers do 6 different lists of struct task. Prio is the index in the array, and the insertion is made in the beginning of every list, so we point the newTask->next pointer to where the pointer inserted in the array goes *(arrayTask + prio) (basically to the first element in that list), then we point this *(arrayTask + prio) (the pointer inserted in the array) to the newTask. I think we're doing it right, yet after hours looking at this I can't be sure of anything...

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, that makes more sense. So, first minor thing, you don't need to do the *(arrayTask + prio) inside the if clause, it's going to fall through and do it regardless if I'm reading your code right.

Secondly, as paddy said, you need to relink the elements in the list after you remove the element you're interested in. I'm curious how you know only the id is being freed?